# Easy recovery of active directory with NTDS and SYSVOL folders? (DSRM PW known!)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, sysvol

I have backups of the active directory `NTDS` and `SYSVOL` folders.
And I know the `DSRM` password of the active directory.

But if I search on Microsoft help for recovering a active directory I only found really bad help instructions.

Is it possible to create a new directory with the same name and copy all files from NTDS and SYSVOL to them?
Or will that not work?

Thanks for any idea! :)

Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Is this your only domain controller?  What state is it in?  (Smoking crater on the floor?  Non-booting but hard drive intact?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost your Active Directory if your server is dead, as that would not work as you can't recover your Active Directory with only those files (you will miss the registry in example too).

You need a system-state backup at the minimum. Please follow Microsoft advice.

[Advice there](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727048.aspx)

To make it short, simply add the backup role and use wbadmin to create a backup, you will be ok after if the server is nto dead yet.

Comment: Ok so there is no chance to get anything... Because I haven't a `wbadmin` backup or something else :(

Comment: @Patrick You lost the array ? or simply the files got corrupted ? If it's the file, I would try it honestly, you got nothing to loose to try